# Getting maximum date and return default date when table is empty

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

How to return date `"1900/12/12 00:00:00"` if table has no rows? I am trying to get max transaction date and it works well if there are rows in the table otherwise I get an error message because of date format in `ToString()`.

```
string d = context.AllTransactions.Where(t => t.ID == OID)
                  .Max(t => t.TransactionDate).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

`TransactionDate` is `NOT NULL datetime` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `DefaultIfEmpty` method before the `.Max` (and as it is linq to entities and you will not be able to create a new transaction object then first project only the dates):

```
var result = context.AllTransactions.Where(t => t.ID == OID)
                    .Select(t => t.TransactionDate)
                    .DefaultIfEmpty(new DateTime(1900,12,12)).Max();
```